# How to get rid of snails on my outdoor potted cacti?

Tags: succulents, cactus, snails

In this past week I found two really tiny snails on two of my potted cacti and have noticed some small damaged areas on others

I live in Southern California which has an arid sunny climate, but we are recovering from cool wet weather. The snails were probably imported from plants that I purchased at garage/yard sales and estate sales.

Is there a spray that I can use?  A powder for use when repotting? I want to stop this before it becomes an infestation.